# Can I think of probabilities as proportions instead?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I am new to probability theory, so bare with me if I do not nail all of the terminology (I will still try my best)! Also, I gave a short "What is my question" sentence, but I invite you to read the whole question if you want the full picture. To help aid in that, I added an index that will help you understand what the separate sections are about at a glance!

**My Question:** [Thinking of probabilities as proportions instead, helps me understand what the probabilities, of abstract mathematical concepts, really mean. Is this allowed and accurate for me to do? Moreover, is this a common technique used? Lastly, why do people describe the probability from the SoftMax function like it is the "chance" of a context-word being near a target-word in the raw-text, when it most certainly is not that prior to the final trained model.]

### Index:

1.) **Introduction to Probability as a Proportion of Magnitude:** Viewing probability from the lens of a normalization technique, and how that allows for it to be seen as a proportion.

2.) **Application to Word2Vec Model:** Brief description of where the probability seemingly lies in the Word2Vec model.

3.) **Misconceptions in Terminology:** How this probability is misinterpreted because it is thought of as a probability in the conventional sense (how the majority of society uses it). And how the misinterpretation of the probability does not allow for one to see how the probabilities meaning changes from un-trained to trained model.

4.) **Mathematical Interpretation of SoftMax Generated Probability:** Showing how mathematically the probability is better described as a proportion.

5.) **From Inherent Meaning to Human Interpretation:** How us as humans draw conclusions of similarity between words from probabilities that seem to have no inherent meaning, along with the word-embedding's meaning.

### Introduction to Probability as a Proportion of Magnitude:

Probabilities are really just scalars of range between $0$ and $1$, that tell you how much of a proportion the entire set's magnitude is made up of by a single item in that set (since the set of probabilities summed together is always $1$). So this really means that probability is really just a normalization technique, and on that same note, this means that literally anything with a magnitude can be made (normalized) into a probability. Going even deeper than that, things (items) without a magnitude can still be made into a probability as long as there is a set of them, since an item being a proportion of a whole set inherently gives that item a magnitude, right? For instance, when we talk about the probability of a coin being heads or tails, we are actually counting what magnitude the proportion of one side of the coin makes up out of the entire set of sides (summed together).

### Application to Word2Vec Model:

The abstract mathematical concept turned to probability I personally am referring to, is cosine similarity. More specifically the probability made by the SoftMax function in the Word2Vec model being referred to as, "likelihood of a word being next to a target word in a text". This sort of implies a "probability" in the conventional sense where we can calculate the true chance of something happening from the start, with just the item and set given, no need for observational analysis (LIKE A COIN FLIP). Where in reality, the Word2Vec probability is one of proportion of total magnitude.

### Misconceptions in Terminology:

This is a problem because people keep describing this probability scalar as a (like I said earlier):

> "The likelihood/probability of a context-word being next to a target word in the raw-text"

Which leads down a slippery slope! Because this is only true at the very **END** of the training in the model, that is the only time the above quote is true. But many people I have interacted with have fallen down this slippery slope. They think that since the probability of a coin-toss from start to end is the "chance"/probability/likelihood of what side a coin will land on, that they can apply this thinking to the probability scalar in Word2Vec, saying that from start to end the probability scalar describes the "chance"/probability/likelihood of a context-word being next to a target-word in the raw-text.

### Mathematical Interpretation of SoftMax Generated Probability:

THIS NEXT PART IS WORDY: In a purely mathematical sense, the probability from the SoftMax function, is really just the **proportion** a single scalar magnitude from the dot product between a single context word-embedding vector and target word-embedding vector (**one item in a set**) makes up out of the sum of scalar magnitudes (**items**) generated individually by every word in the vocabulary via the same dot-product process (**the set of items**). And this is verifiable by the fact that a higher scalar magnitude from the the dot-product of two word-embeddings, will always have a higher probability than a smaller scalar magnitude from the dot-product of two word-embeddings.

### From Inherent Meaning to Human Interpretation:

In a purely mathematical sense, there is no inherent meaning created by this probability, because the proportions of magnitudes are created from an abstract mathematical concept, cosine similarity. They are only proportions not "chances". "No inherent meaning" in the conventional sense, by giving you a **"chance"** of something happening, like the side of a coin flip being heads.

We as human beings realize that cosine similarity scalar (simplified to dot-product between two vectors) tells us how close two vectors are in vector space. Which means that two word-embedding **vectors** that are super close to each other in vector space will give high probability scalar (due to that fact that they will first give a high cosine similarity scalar). This means, we as humans, can assign meaning to the probability scalar, by stating a fact that the higher a probability scalar is, the closer two word-embedding vectors are in vector space. Using this statement/fact like an axiom, we can now try and make words  that appear close to each other in the raw-text, have word-embedding vectors that are close to each other in vector space (similar). But this alone still gives no inherent meaning of word similarity being correlated with two words being close to each other in vector space. We are missing the final puzzle piece, and arguably the most important piece. We use the **distributional hypothesis** to assign meaning to the word-embedding vectors (and the probability/proportion as well). Since two word-embedding vectors being close in vector space means two words are close in the raw text, then by the distributional hypothesis, we can state that two word-embedding vectors being close in vector space means that the two words represented by these vectors are semantically similar.

So by the end of the training the pipeline will look like so, two semantically similar words will be trained/changed to have word-embedding vectors near each other in vector space -> which means the cosine similarity will be higher -> which means the probability scalar will be higher -> which finally means that we can assign meaning to this probability, stating, "The higher the probability scalar, the more semantically similar two words are (in a trained model)".

And so in conclusion, I think that probability in many cases, especially here, should be called proportion instead. Because what we are really observing most of the time from the "probability" is the proportion of the magnitude one item of a set makes up out of the whole set, normalized to $[0,1]$.

Comment: You can think of probabilities as monkeys doing origami if it helps you understand the subject better. Are you looking for something deeper?

Comment: If you still have a question pending, is it possible for you to drastically reduce the size of your posting, and still present the question that you want help with?  If not, is it possible for you to re-organize your posting into sections, and (at the start of your posting) provide an overview of the various sections in your posted question, and what the significance is of each question?  Probably through no fault of your own, it is difficult to understand what question that you are asking for help with.

Comment: @user2661923 I totally get that! I would love to do that, I tried looking up how to make those hypertext links that make you jump to somewhere further on the same page. But I couldn't find any info on how to do that for stack-exchange. I will still add the headers and index though!

Comment: @JohnDouma Probably something a little deeper than monkeys doing origami hahaha (I like that one), but maybe you can see what I am saying better after I reformat it.

Comment: See the **Links** section of [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help inserting internet links (e.g. of other webpages) directly into your posting.  Beyond that, there is no need for the *hypertext* link that you are referring to.  If you simply state up front, the purpose of your question, you can then (for example) use `-----` to divide your posting into sections, and use `**Title of Section**` to highlight each section.  Readers will then have no problem **manually** navigating through your posting.

Comment: @user2661923 I just added the "small headers", for people who are reading right now, I am working on the index

Comment: It sounds like you might be missing something about the use of [generative models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model) in machine learning (or of statistical models in general). The idea is to *imagine* that the data comes from a certain probability distribution with unknown parameters and then to estimate those parameters by looking at the data. We don't usually believe the model is true--obviously the true mechanism underlying human language production is much more complicated--but the simpler probabilistic model can still make useful predictions.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to think of probabilities as proportions, if you like. In fact, if you take the frequentist view of probability (which is common enough), then probabilities _are_ proportions — they're the proportion of the number of events under consideration to the total number of events possible!

Comment: @Karl You're on the right track! I definitely believe the model is "true" in the sense that the final model can accurately model semantic similarity between words. But what I really mean, can be explained best in an example. In a classical probability scenario like a coin flip, we have a well-defined set of possible outcomes, and we know the parameters governing the system, PRIOR to the running any tests. Therefore, we can purely calculate probabilities analytically, with no need for empirical observation.

Comment: @Karl So if we encountered someone that said, "I flipped a coin $10$ times, and $70\%$ of the time it landed on heads, and $30\%$ of the time it landed on tails. This means that if you flip a coin, there is a $70\%$ chance for it to land on heads!". It would be outstandingly easy to disprove, you have all the parameters to mathematically do so, and so you can use probability theory to assess whether this is consistent with a fair coin or if it suggests a biased coin. Now let's perform this example with a Word2Vec model.

Comment: @Karl If someone came up to you and said, "After training the first Word2Vec model, there is a $70\%$ chance that the word `bus` will appear next to `xylophone` in the raw text!" This sounds preposterous, how could bus be that semantically similar to xylophone (given we are following the distributional hypothesis)!? Then they say, "Well, disprove it". But you literally cannot! Because unlike the coin flip, you do not have the parameters in advance. The only way you could disprove it, would be through empirical evaluation (this is literally what models like Word2Vec do under the hood!).

Comment: @Karl This is because probabilities generated by the model are not directly interpretable as probabilities in the same sense as coin flips. The output of the SoftMax function, does not represent a direct, objective probability of occurrence like a traditional probability. And so, to me, it does not seem like a probability, but instead just purely fitting data, and probabilities are normalizing technique utilized, not for the purpose of explaining how the model operates, but because it makes calculating loss easier.

Comment: @Karl So that's why I argue, calling these "probabilities", proportions, would make more intuitive sense! It better describes the nature of what is happening.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex That's awesome! Call me a frequentist then hahaha! I love your answer, do you mind making it a full blown answer, so I could upvote it?

Comment: @Karl I re-read your comment, and I have one last thought! You say, "probability distribution with unknown parameters and then to estimate those parameters by looking at the data", this is a perfect example of why I think that the term "proportion" works better! To me "a proportional distribution with unknown parameters and then to estimate those parameters by looking at the data", makes more intuitive sense. Since we are in the presence of unknowns, focusing on calculations discovered through observing/manipulating the data found, while probability brings on the connotation of having priors.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between your coin and text examples. In both cases we start with a parametrized model that stands in for the true underlying physics and defines a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) on the space of observable outcomes. Then, given some evidence, we can find the parameter values that maximize the likelihood of the evidence, and use these parameter settings to make probabilistic statements about future outcomes.

Comment: So I think you might be conflating two things: (1) the statistics we calculate from the observed data in order to fit or update the model, which in many cases are proportions; and (2) the quantitative predictions that the resulting model makes about a hypothetical unobserved data point, which are in the form of probabilities (not necessarily equal to proportions seen in the training data).